# In 2 Timothy 4:6 what is the meaning of the phrase "drink offering"?

Tags: exodus, leviticus, 2-timothy

2 Timothy 4 (NASB)

> [6]For I am already being poured out as a **drink offering**, and the time of my departure has come.

Leviticus 23 (NASB)

> [13]Its grain offering shall then be two-tenths of an ephah of fine flour mixed with oil, an offering by fire to the Lord for a soothing aroma, with its **drink offering**, a fourth of a hin of wine.

Exodus 29 (NASB)

> [40]and there shall be one-tenth of an ephah of fine flour mixed with one-fourth of a hin of beaten oil, and one-fourth of a hin of wine for a **drink offering** with one lamb.

Could Paul have been referencing to the Mosaic Law for drink offering was part of sacrifice to the Lord

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Greek text of 2 Tim. 4:6 states,

> <sup>Ϛʹ</sup> Ἐγὼ γὰρ ἤδη σπένδομαι καὶ ὁ καιρὸς τῆς ἐμῆς ἀναλύσεώς ἐφέστηκεν <sup>TR, 1550</sup>

which may be translated into English as,

> <sup>6</sup> For I am already being poured out, and the time of my departure is imminent.

The verb σπένδομαι is declined in the middle voice from the lemma σπένδω. While it occurs twice in the Greek New Testament, it occurs approximately 20 times in 19 verses in the Greek Septuagint, commonly as a translation of the Hebrew verb נָסַךְ. The related Hebrew noun נֶסֶךְ was translated in the Septuagint by the Greek noun σπονδή, meaning “a drink offering.”<sup>1</sup> The verb σπένδω thus means to offer or pour out (a drink offering or libation).<sup>2</sup>

In the Tanakh, the נֶסֶךְ consisted of a fourth of a hin of wine,<sup>3</sup> although Pagans poured out blood for their drink offerings—a practice considered unacceptable to Yahveh.<sup>4</sup>

Accoording to the Babylonian Talmud,<sup>5</sup> the blood of the bloody animal offering (זֶבַח) was a prerequisite for the drink offering (נֶסֶךְ) to be offered. Perhaps, then, this is the practice the apostle Paul alludes to when he mentions that he is being poured out and the time of his departure (i.e., death<sup>6</sup>) is imminent.

According to Joseph Henry Thayer,<sup>7</sup>

> σπένδεσθαι, to be offered as a libation, is figuratively used of one whose blood is poured out in a violent death for the cause of God: Phil. 2:17 (see θυσία, b. fin.); 2 Tim. 4:6.

---

### References

Arndt, William; Bauer, Walter; Danker, Frederick William. *A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature.* 3rd ed. Chicago: U of Chicago P, 2000.

[*Babylonian Talmud*](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l0.htm) (תלמוד בבלי). Vilna: Romm, 1835.

Liddell, Henry George; Scott, Robert; et al. *A Greek-English Lexicon.* 9th ed. Oxford: Clarendon, 1940.

Wilke, Christian Gottlob. [*A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament: Being Grimm Wilke’s Clavis Novi Testamenti.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC) Trans. Thayer, Joseph Henry.Ed. Grimm, Carl Ludwig Wilibald. Rev. ed. New York: American Book, 1889.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> LSJ, p. 1629
<sup>2</sup> BDAG, p. 937; LSJ, p. 1626; Thayer, p. [583](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC&pg=PA583#v=onepage&q&f=true)
<sup>3</sup> cp. Exo. 29:40: 
<sup>4</sup> Psa. 16:4
<sup>5</sup> Tractate Zevachim, Chapter 4, Gemara, Folio [44a](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l5104.htm):

> אתאן לרבנן דתניא נסכי בהמה חייבין עליהן משום פיגול מפני שדם הזבח מתירן ליקרב דברי רבי מאיר

<sup>6</sup> BDAG, p. 67; LSJ, p. 112, 2.; Thayer, p. [39](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC&pg=PA39#v=onepage&q&f=true), 2.
<sup>7</sup> Thayer, p. [583](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC&pg=PA583#v=onepage&q&f=true)

Answer (score 0):

In the old testament, sacrifices of lamb would be offered to God. At the end, they would pour a glass of wine on the altar signifying that the ritual is complete. Paul is similarizing the end of his journey with the drink offering poured at the end of the sacrifice ritual in the old testtament (Many jews read his letters and understood his refrence to the drink offering).

Comment: Welcome. BH.SE. This answer would be much more convincing if you had references to support what you say. If you say, "In the old testament...", then tell the readers where. If you are suggesting Paul's simile has some basis in his own actions, then include the support you have for it.